# ¿Obtener acceso al contenido de iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, asp.net, mvc

Que tal amigos espero me puedan apoyar con algunas dudas que tengo.

Estoy cargando una **pagina en un iframe**, y cuando intento acceder al **contentDocument** me devuelve el siguiente error **DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:55432" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**, entiendo que esto es normal ya que se tratan de dos dominimos distintos.

Me gustaria saber si existen un modo de obtener acceso (me refiero a si conocen un js que permita esa funcionalidad) ó en mi caso estoy utilizando *ASP.NET MVC* y si existe una alternativa para poder resolver mi dilema.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) que permite enviar/recibir informacion entre sitios que no pertenezcan al mismo domino.

Para enviar un mensaje desde el iframe seria:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').postMessage('hola', '*');
```

El parametro * indica que le enviara el mensaje a cualquier sitio o iframe que este escuchando por un mensaje. Entonces para recibirlo en la pagina seria asi:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
   if(e.origin.indexOf('url-de-tu-sitio) > 0)
   {
      // se envio un mensaje desde tu sitio
   }
});
```

Esto funciona de ambas formas, tanto desde tu pagina para el iframe como desde el iframe para la pagina que lo ejecuta. Claro, esto quiere decir que tendrias que tener control de la pagina que sera cargada en el iframe para poder enviar el mensaje o de lo contrario no podras.

Actualmente esta es la unica manera de hacerlo sin tener que agregar las politicas de origen CORS.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu apoyo, pero creo sera un poco complicado por que no tengo el control de la pagina cargada en el iframe.

Comment: Creo que no hay mucho que puedas hacer entonces. Como ya lo mencionaste, no se puede acceder a una pagina con un dominio diferente.